# Refresh or load background image with Full Ajax for Joomla on menu item click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, joomla

i am trying to produce a browser refresh in the background after a click on Joomla menu item.

My issue is i am already using ajax to process content component and other element on the page to refresh in one position but i need these to be updated on this way:
- user click on menu item then new background and new content are loaded

When I hit F5 / refresh page then background is normally changed and it is corespondent to active menuItemId; Just to note that ajax change URL based on menuItemID but he is not changing background which need`s to be pulled from css-

I am using simple css background state based on menu item ID on this way:

html part

```
<body id="background<?php echo JRequest::getInt( 'Itemid' ); ?>">
```

css (101, 102, 103...114 are Menu item ID`s)

```
 #background101{ background:transparent url(../images/1.jpg) no-repeat 100% 100%; }
    #background102 { background:transparent url(../images/2.jpg) no-repeat 100% 100%;}
    #background103 { background:transparent url(../images/3.jpg) no-repeat 100% 100%; }
```

Plugin installed in Joomla is [FullAjax plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/scripts/13293)

I read manual about configuration but there is no explanation how to refresh page/site background based on menuItemID

JavaScript code, parameters for FullAjax

```
    FLAX.Filter.add({url:'/', id:fullAjaxId});
 FLAX.Filter.add({query:['task=weblink','task=profile','task=user.login','task=user.logout','task=article.edit'],  type:'nowrap'});
 FLAX.Filter.on('beforewrap', function(o) {
  var id = o.el.getAttribute('id'), regExt = /.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|mp3|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|pdf|txt|odf|ods)$/i;
  if(id == ('login-form') || id == ('form-login') || (o.el.href && (regExt.test(o.el.href) || o.el.href.indexOf('#') != -1))){return false;}
 });
 FLAX.directLink();FLAX.Default.sprt_url = '!';
 FLAX.linkEqual['!ax!'+fullAjaxId+'!'] = 'ajx';FLAX.linkEqual['[~q~]'] = '?';
 /* fix for mootools 'domready', uncomment if need */
 /* FLAX.Html.onall('load', function(o){window.fireEvent('domready');}); */
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it not works because `<body>` not changes, you need a some coding for change it after each ajax call.

if you have options `Check the active menu item` enabled then you can do next:

```js
FLAX.Html.onall('load', function(){
    if(fullAjaxMItems.length){
       //set id using MooTools
       document.id(document.body).set('id', 'background' + fullAjaxMItems[0]);
    }
  });
```

if this options is not enabled, then just add the variable in you template `<head>` that will keep current menu item id, like:

```html
<script>
  var currentItemId = <?php echo JRequest::getInt( 'Itemid' ); ?>;
</script>
```

and then in the plugin configuration:

```js
FLAX.Html.onall('load', function(){
  if(window.currentItemId){
     //set id using MooTools
     document.id(document.body).set('id', 'background' + currentItemId);
  }
});
```

Comment: Excellent @Fedik background changes now depending to menuItemId. Is it possible to add loader and fadeIn effect to background?

Comment: this is also solved using css3 transition effect

-o-transition:color .1s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
-ms-transition:color .1s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
-moz-transition:color .1s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
-webkit-transition:color .1s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
transition:color .1s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;